Unable to upload file due to ItemNotFound error for .default scope with microsfot graph
I am trying to upload a file using a microsoft graph api. As per the requirement I am using Client credential flows with .default permission. It is generating token and able to fetch user, calendar events etc.
While uploading a file using the same scoped token, it is giving following error.
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/root:/MyFolder/file.xlsx:/content
Error:
{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"Item not found",
The same code works when I am using the logged in user token. Which means the file path needs to be adjusted for the Client Credential flow.
Does anyone know what should be the file path while using api with .default scope of Client Credential flow.
Code Sample:
Code to generate a token
POST : login.microsoftonline.com/2808f13e-3eee-4625-a70c-f4c8dab8aa28/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 182

client_id=429fb663-7bb7-41d1-9a22-6c816f6ac288
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=4dI8Q~nKw2-07SekjrqZC8~8SFKxktcRUn2vMcRJ
&grant_type=client_credentials

Code to upload a file
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/root:/file.xlsx:/content
Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file.

Note: Same file upload code works when using user logged in token.
